# my.cnfの場所を探して内容を確認したいのですが、見つかりません

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

**my.cnfの場所を探して内容を確認したいのですが、見つかりません**
・my.cnfは、オプションファイルなので必ず設置されているとは限らない？

---

**mysql --help | grep my.cnf**
・このコマンドの意味は？
・設置していた場合の、読込順を表示するだけ？
・必ず設置されているとは限らない？

---

**~/.my.cnf**
・試しに、下記コマンドを打ってみたのですが、見つかりませんでした
・探し方が悪い？

```
# cd ~/                                                                                                                                
# ls -la
```

---

**my.cnfの場所はどうやって探すのでしょうか？**
・下記コマンドを打ってみたのですが、反応なしでした

```
# grep my.cnf
```

---

**環境**
・MySQL5.6
・CentOS6.4

Comment: [これ](http://qiita.com/yoheiW@github/items/bcbcd11e89bfc7d7f3ff)を参考にしてみて下さい。

Comment: 現在の環境が分からないのでなんとも…デフォルトファイルが変わってると参照先も変更されるし…、とりあえずコマンドだけ…ヘルプから"Default options are read from the following files in the given order”の項目を検索して表示しようとしています。`mysql --help`：MySQLコマンドのヘルプを表示する。 ／ ` | grep my.cnf`：表示されたヘルプの内容から"my.cnf"をgrep検索する。grep前に受け渡しがない、ファイル名の指定がない状態だと検索できません。(検索対象がないので当たり前ですね)……それ以外となるとBLUEPIXYさんのリンクを参考に探すしかないんじゃないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysql --help | grep my.cnf

環境によっては デフォルトの my.cnf の場所が違うので 確認してます。
--help でヘルプを表示してますが、情報量が多いので my.cnf で絞り込んでるだけです。
詳しくは `mysql --help` を実行して表示される内容を読んでください。

> ~/.my.cnf

`~/.my.cnf` は実行ユーザの HOME ディレクトリになります。
MySQLサーバーの設定ファイルとしてはふさわしくありませんが、各ユーザのクライアントの設定を書くのに適しています。

> my.cnfの場所はどうやって探すのでしょうか？

`find / -type f -ls  | fgrep my.cnf` を root で実行してみてください。

また、mysqlサーバーの起動時にオプションパラメータ `--defaults-extra-file=path` で指定する方法や、環境変数 `MYSQL_HOME` で指定する方法があるようです。

お使いの環境がどうなっているか mysqlサーバーの起動スクリプトを見るなどして確認されると良いと思います。

Comment: 「--help でヘルプを表示してますが、情報量が多いので my.cnf で絞り込んでるだけ」。やはりそうなのですね。「find / -type f -ls  | fgrep my.cnf を root で実行」。無事見つかりました。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 1):

yumで入れたのか、tarボールで入れたのか、オプションにより保存先が変わってきます。

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)で"yum"で入れた場合、/etc/my.cnfがデフォルトとなっています。

Comment: 検索してみたら、「/etc/my.cnf」にありました

Answer (score 1):

masaさんの回答で見つからない場合は、下記で全検索してみると見つかると思います。

```
find / | grep my.cnf
```

後は上記と同じ感じですがlocateコマンドをインストールして探すかです。
他にもファイルを探すときは便利なのでお勧めです。

```
yum install mlocate
updatedb
locate my.cnf
```

Comment: 「find / | grep my.cnf」を試したら、無事見つかりました。「locateコマンド」は初めて知りました。まだまだ知らないコマンドがあるなと思いました。大変参考になりました